# Python: Most frequent character counter

Tags: python, string, frequency

I am trying to create a program that asks a user to input a string and then displays the most frequently occurring characters in the string. I cannot use built in features such as dictionary. I think my problem now is that I have an infinite loop. How can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
string = input('Enter a string:')

#space for most popular character
pop_char = ''
#initialize number of times character appears
num = 0
#initialize index
index = 0

# pick one character at a time
for ch in string:
    #initialize character counter
    cc=0

#go through entire string and compare the character to the string characters
    while index < len(string):

        #if they are the same (converted to lower case), tally one to cc
        if ch.lower() == string[index].lower():
            cc = cc + 1
            index = index + 1

        #if count is greater than or equal to previous count, use this for
        #popular character
        if cc >= num:
            num = cc
            pop_char = ch

        else:
            index = index + 1
print('The most frequently occuring letter(s):', pop_char)
```

Comment: seems like you have an indentations problem, the second `if` should be in the first one scope

Comment: Are you getting out of the processing of the `if cc >= num:
            num = cc
            pop_char = ch` stanza

Comment: Why can you not use built-in features? Is this a homework assignment? Can you use builtin string methods such as `string.count` ? Do you have any other restrictions?

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. The code is working after changing the >= to >. However it is only displaying one letter in the even of a tie. Which I am still trying to figure out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`if cc >= num:` should be `if cc > num:`

On your first iteration, the first letter will equal the first letter of the string (obviously) and you will enter `if ch.lower() == string[index].lower():`. This will set `cc` to `1` which will, in turn, set `num` to `1` as well.

As they are both equal, as long as the second letter is not the same as the first, you will have an infinite loop that only enters the `if cc >= num` section and never update `index` past `1`.

Comment: Thanks! My code still displays only one of the most frequent numbers if there is a tie though. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: `pop_char` be a string and add ch to `pop_char` if `cc==num` rather. (You have to be careful not to add the existing character to `pop_char` though.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are changing the index value in two separate `if` clauses and you are using a `>=` instead of a `>` to check for the frequent character.

Imagine the very first letter running through your loop. On the first pass through, it will compare it to itself and increment the index and `cc`. `cc` is then updated to `1` and `num` is updated to `1`. On the next run through, your letter doesn't match the second letter, but it does pass the second `if` case, guaranteeing that none of your values change and your `index` does not increment. I suggest changing `cc >= num` to `cc > num`.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use any methods at all just use a double for loop:

```
def most_common():
    s = input('Enter a string:').lower()
    coun = 0
    best = ""
    for ch in s:
        cn = 0
        for c in s:
            cn += ch == c # will be True or False 1/0
        if cn >= coun: 
            if cn == coun: # catch letters that have equal count
                if ch in best: # avoid adding same char twice
                    continue
                best += ch # id equal and not already added concat to the stirng
            else:
                best = ch # else just set best
            coun = cn
    return 'The most frequently occuring letter(s): {}'.format(best)
```

Which works for characters that have equal counts:

```
In [14]: most_common()
Enter a string:foobar
Out[14]: 'The most frequently occuring letter(s): o'

In [15]: most_common()
Enter a string:foobb
Out[15]: 'The most frequently occuring letter(s): ob'
```

Comment: @River,  their code does not work as it is supposed to so no they don't have a solution

Comment: Alright, suite yourself, just trying to give helpful suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'm going to try to adapt some of this to my current code to catch ties in frequency.

Comment: @jeff78, no worries,  the tie logic can be directly translated to your own code.